# Rendering a portion of code (tablesorter with selectize) everytime I load a React component

Tags: reactjs, tablesorter, dropdown, selectize.js

My app is rendering a portion of code everytime I load a component. This is the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/rLvfa8rn/

I'm trying to implement this http://jsfiddle.net/Unspecified/qrqJv/1/ on my tablesorter table.

The problem is with the portion of lines 71-121, there's a dropdown of Selectize.js rendering everytime I call the page:

```
Selectize.define( 'clear_selection', function ( options ) {
        var self = this;
        var title = options.title || 'Sin filtro';
        //Overriding because, ideally you wouldn't use header & clear_selection simultaneously
        self.plugins.settings.dropdown_header = {
            title: title
        };
        this.require( 'dropdown_header' );
        self.setup = (function () {
            var original = self.setup;
            return function () {
                original.apply( this, arguments );
                this.$dropdown.on( 'mousedown', '.selectize-dropdown-header', function ( e ) {
                    self.setValue( '' );
                    self.close();
                    self.blur();
                    return false;
                });
            }
        })()
    });
```

I put all the code because maybe the problem is another.

Comment: Well, all the problem was in the var selectize({
                hideSelected: false,
                dropdownParent: 'body', the option: dropdownParent: 'body' was the problem, it's a know bug of selectize I guess. Removing that option works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, all the problem was in the var selectize({

```
var selectize({
    hideSelected: false,
    dropdownParent: 'body'
```

the option: dropdownParent: 'body' was the problem, it's a know bug of selectize I guess. Removing that option works fine.